# writeRaster vs write.table or .tif vs .csv

Tags: r, tiff, raster, netcdf

Someone sent me some `R` code to read a `netCDF` file using the `R` package `raster`, among others.  The code creates a series of `*.tif` files.  Unfortunately, I am not very familiar with `raster`, `*.tif` files or `netCDF` files.  So, I have tried to alter the `R` code to also write `*.csv` files.  I think the code below writes the same grid cell data in `*.tif` format and `*.csv` format.  However, I am not certain.  I am hoping someone may be able to verify that the data in both formats are the same.  Ideally, I would like to be able to open the `*.tif` files and conduct the verification myself.  How can I do that?

Perhaps a direct comparison is not possible if the `*.tif` files only contain an image instead of numbers.  In that case I would like to verify that the image in the `*.tif` files correspond to the data in the `*.csv` files

Below the `R` code are the contents of a `*.csv` file with a follow-up question about the column and row 'headings'.

```
setwd('c:/users/mark w miller/netCDF/')

my.file <- "my.netCDF.nc"
my.var1 <- "my.variable"

library(ncdf) 
library(rgdal) 
library(chron) 
library(fields) 

file    <- open.ncdf(my.file)
long    <- get.var.ncdf(file, varid="lon")
lat     <- get.var.ncdf(file, varid="lat")
time    <- get.var.ncdf(file, varid="time")
my.varb <- get.var.ncdf(file, varid=my.var1)

#netCDF to raster
library(raster)

r       <- brick(my.file, varname = my.var1)

#Crop spatial coverage
e       <- extent(255,265,35,45)
rc      <- crop(r, e, bylayer=TRUE)

lat2    <- lat[  lat >=  35 & lat  <=  45]
long2   <- long[long >= 255 & long <= 265]

list1   <- unstack(rc)
rs      <- stack(list1)

for(i in 1:5){
     r2 <- 1+(i-1)*12
     s2 <- 2+(i-1)*12
     a2 <- rs[[r2]]
     b2 <- rs[[s2]]
     m2 <- stack(a2,b2)
     my.var <- overlay(m2, fun=function(x,y) {(x+y)}, unstack=TRUE, recycle=FALSE) 
     f2 <- 1999+i

     writeRaster(my.var, filename=paste("my.var", f2, ".tif"), format="GTiff")

     my.var2 <- as.matrix(my.var, nrow=length(lat2), byrow=TRUE)

     write.table(my.var2, file = paste0("my.var", f2, ".csv"), quote = FALSE, sep=",", col.names = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)
}
```

Here are the rounded contents of one `*.csv` file:

```
1.0,0.9,0.8,0.8,0.7,0.7,0.8,0.8,1.0,1.0
1.0,0.8,0.6,0.5,0.4,0.5,0.7,0.9,1.0,1.0
1.0,0.7,0.5,0.4,0.3,0.4,0.7,1.0,1.0,1.0
0.0,0.5,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.6,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0
0.0,0.6,0.5,0.4,0.5,0.8,1.0,2.0,2.0,2.0
1.0,0.7,0.6,0.5,0.6,1.0,1.0,2.0,2.0,2.0
1.0,0.9,0.8,0.7,0.9,1.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0
1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,1.0,2.0
2.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,1.0,1.0,2.0
1.0,1.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,3.0
```

Given that:

```
lat2
# [1] 44.5 43.5 42.5 41.5 40.5 39.5 38.5 37.5 36.5 35.5

long2
# [1] 255.5 256.5 257.5 258.5 259.5 260.5 261.5 262.5 263.5 264.5
```

Can I safely add the following column and row names to each `*.csv` file?

```
      255.5 256.5 257.5 258.5 259.5 260.5 261.5 262.5 263.5 264.5
44.5  1.0,0.9,0.8,0.8,0.7,0.7,0.8,0.8,1.0,1.0
43.5  1.0,0.8,0.6,0.5,0.4,0.5,0.7,0.9,1.0,1.0
42.5  1.0,0.7,0.5,0.4,0.3,0.4,0.7,1.0,1.0,1.0
41.5  0.0,0.5,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.6,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0
40.5  0.0,0.6,0.5,0.4,0.5,0.8,1.0,2.0,2.0,2.0
39.5  1.0,0.7,0.6,0.5,0.6,1.0,1.0,2.0,2.0,2.0
38.5  1.0,0.9,0.8,0.7,0.9,1.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0
37.5  1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,1.0,2.0
36.5  2.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,1.0,1.0,2.0
35.5  1.0,1.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,3.0
```

Thank you for any advice.  The actual netCDF file is very large.  If I can figure out how to subset it and save it in the same netCDF format I might try to upload it somewhere.

**EDIT**

Below is code to create simulated data, convert those simulated data into a netCDF file and analyze that netCDF file as in the code above:

```
setwd('c:/users/mark w miller/netCDF/')

library(raster)
library(ncdf) 
library(rgdal) 
library(chron) 
library(fields)
library(sp)

set.seed(1234)

x = seq( 255, 269, length =  8)
y = seq(  36,  40, length =  5)
xy <- expand.grid(x,y)

z  <- rnorm(nrow(xy), 10, 1)
rc <- data.frame(xy,z)

raster.rc1 <- rasterFromXYZ(rc, res=c(2,1), crs=CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"))

z  <- rnorm(nrow(xy), 10, 1)
rc <- data.frame(xy,z)

raster.rc2 <- rasterFromXYZ(rc, res=c(2,1), crs=CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"))

z  <- rnorm(nrow(xy), 10, 1)
rc <- data.frame(xy,z)

raster.rc3 <- rasterFromXYZ(rc, res=c(2,1), crs=CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"))

z  <- rnorm(nrow(xy), 10, 1)
rc <- data.frame(xy,z)

raster.rc4 <- rasterFromXYZ(rc, res=c(2,1), crs=CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"))


all.years <- list(raster.rc1, raster.rc2, raster.rc3, raster.rc4)

#all.rc    <- stack(all.years)

all.rc    <- brick(all.years)

writeRaster(all.rc, filename="example.netCDF.nc", format="CDF", bylayer=TRUE, overwrite=TRUE)


my.file   <- open.ncdf('example.netCDF.nc')
my.file

long   <- get.var.ncdf(my.file, varid="longitude")
lat    <- get.var.ncdf(my.file, varid="latitude")
time   <- get.var.ncdf(my.file, varid="value")
my.var <- get.var.ncdf(my.file, varid="variable")

long
# [1] 255 257 259 261 263 265 267 269

lat
# [1] 40 39 38 37 36

time
# [1] 1 2 3 4

my.var

r       <- brick('example.netCDF.nc', varname = 'variable')

#Crop spatial coverage
e       <- extent(257,267,37,39)
rc      <- crop(r, e, bylayer=TRUE)

lat2    <- lat[  lat >=  37 & lat  <=  39]
lat2
long2   <- long[long >= 257 & long <= 267]
long2

list1   <- unstack(rc)
rs      <- stack(list1)

for(i in 1:2){
     r2 <- 1+(i-1)*2
     s2 <- 2+(i-1)*2
     a2 <- rs[[r2]]
     b2 <- rs[[s2]]
     m2 <- stack(a2,b2)
     my.sim <- overlay(m2, fun=function(x,y) {(x+y)}, unstack=TRUE, recycle=FALSE) 
     f2 <- 2010+i

     writeRaster(my.sim, filename=paste("my.sim", f2, ".tif"), format="GTiff")

     my.sim2 <- as.matrix(my.sim, nrow=length(lat2), byrow=TRUE)

     write.table(my.sim2, file = paste0("my.sim", f2, ".csv"), quote = FALSE, sep=",", col.names = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)
}
```

Comment: I would start with as.data.frame(subset(rc, 1), xy=TRUE)

Comment: @mdsumner  Thank you.  That seems to extract one layer of data and convert it to a data frame.  Perhaps I can somehow use `create.ncdf` to turn that data frame into a netCDF file.

Comment: Use writeRaster to create a netcdf file

Comment: @mdsumner Thank you.  I have added code to create simulated data, convert those simulated data into a netCDF file and analyze that netCDF file as in the original code.  My objective now is to verify that the `*.tif` files contain the same data (or at least the same information) as the `*.csv` files.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a general way to compare the contents of `*.tiff` files and `*.csv` files.  Comparing the contents of an example `*.csv` file with its `*.tiff` plot makes me feel confident that their contents are the same.

Below that I show how to display the data within the `*.tiff` file.

```
setwd('c:/users/mmiller21/netCDF/')

library(raster)

# Here are the contents of 'my.sim2011.csv':
#
# 18.31545067  20.22907639  20.34417152  18.11485672  17.93542576  19.52469158
# 19.20878696  19.43614769  18.41953754  16.42925882  22.05830574  18.31794167
#
# compared with the plot of 'my.sim 2011 .tif'

jpeg(filename = "my.sim.2011.jpeg")

  r <- raster('my.sim 2011 .tif')
  plot(r)
  title(main='my.sim 2011 .tif')

dev.off()
```

[image]

```
# Here are the contents of 'my.sim2012.csv':
#
# 18.92995739  20.68585968  20.44407845  20.53401566  19.1156435   20.70266819
# 19.04809856  20.76659107  20.50794601  18.52109146  20.92043018  19.91858768
#
# compared with the plot of 'my.sim 2012 .tif'

jpeg(filename = "my.sim.2012.jpeg")

  r <- raster('my.sim 2012 .tif')
  plot(r)
  title(main='my.sim 2012 .tif')

dev.off()
```

[image]

Here is code to display the data in one example `*.tiff` file.  That data does match the data within the corresponding `*.csv` file.

```
r <- raster('my.sim 2011 .tif')

r[1,]
[1] 18.31545 20.22908 20.34417 18.11486 17.93543 19.52469

r[2,]
[1] 19.20879 19.43615 18.41954 16.42926 22.05831 18.31794
```